# A web storage site with direct file link

Tags: wordpress, cloud-storage, web, woocommerce

I am building a woocommerce based site, in which I want to sell a certain excel file.

I've been struggling find a web storage site which will allow me to put a link to my digital product in Woocommerce, so after the client pays he will be able to download the file immediately by clicking the link.

So far I have tried dropbox, mega, Ondrive, and several more. In all cases one of the two next options occured: Either it took me to a page in the site and only then it allowed me to download the file, or it did downloaded the file, but in other name and without the file extension!

Comment: What about Amazon S3 service? It allows you to hotlink files.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative that I know of is [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/). First of all upload the files and then click on the share button on top.

[image]

This will give you a link which is of the form

`https://drive.google.com/open?id=FILE_ID`

Make a note of the `FILE_ID`.

On your website, create the following link.

`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID`

where, `FILE_ID` is the `ID` that you got from the `Google Drive`.

This will result in a direct file download.

**Caution:** Be aware that once a file is downloaded, the `FILE_ID` will be public and anyone can download the file without your permission and without paying money. If you want a foolproof method, consider hosting the files on your servers itself.

Comment: This doesn't work for large files. I think the limit is 50MB. If it is over 50MB then it will redirect to a page warning that it is too large to scan for viruses.

Answer (score 1):

This is not answering your question but it is an alternative to fixing your problem.

You can use the [Easy Digital Downloads](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-digital-downloads/)plugin. You can use that to sell your excels sheets.

This plugin is free although add-ons cost extra.

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox works, just make sure the copied link ends with `?dl=1` instead of `?dl=0`.

For example:

> `https://www.dropbox.com/s/abcabc123123abc/My_Awesome_File.xlsx`**`?dl=1`**